# how to upgrade scipy or numpy in EPD?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, epd-python

Their versions are old in EPD.
I have tried pip,but it seems they are enclosed in EPD.
Is there a way to upgrade them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do type this command in a terminal:

```
  enpkg numpy
  enpkg scipy
```

`enpkg` is the package manager for EPD. If you upgrade your EPD installation to the new Canopy  Python distribution, you will find a UI for the package manager.